# Resolve charset issue after the issue

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a DB taken from another DB that is not under my control. The output of the original DB is messy and gives us datas like: "`ã?`" instead of "`ñ`".

How to clean this with PHP ? Is there a functions available or do I have to str_replace all these by hand ?

Comment: php won't fix that for you. You could write a script that looks through your data letter by letter and do "If ã then ñ" and so on. Sounds like you got the data in a sketchy way.

Comment: I think you're right :/ in hex it is C3833F and 3F = ?. Means there is no way to get back to the original data. No bijection here.